# Use of string literal for Objective-C selectors is deprecated; use '#selector' instead

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I have the following code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //Looks for single or multiple taps.
            let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

When running the application This error occurs when the work of error repair another mistake happens

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error due to the updates to the swift language, change your tap selector for this:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
```

Make sure that the method dismissKeyboard is in the same view controller, if its not you'll need to do #selector(WhateverHasThatMethod.dismissKeyboard)

Also, make sure that the dismissKeyboard method actually exists, it should be something along the lines of:

```
func dismissKeyboard(){
    YourInputField.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: not working  i get breakpoint error !

Comment: self Posting.LoginViewController 0x00000001556537c0
tap UITapGestureRecognizer 0x00000001556537c0
UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: I have updated my answer to your question with a bit more information, I think you might be missing the method that actually hides your keyboards.

Comment: thnx for your help but i get same error !

Comment: i have update my question  with  my function

Comment: I see, you are doing view.endEditing(true), your error is that view is not an input field. You should have an outlet to whatever it is that is showing your keyboard, for example, if you are using a text input and you linked it to your view controller with @IBOutlet weak var EmailAddressInputField: UITextField!, you should call EmailAddressInputField.endEditing(true)

Comment: thnx for your  help !

Comment: No problem! happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 2.2, use this instead:
`#selector(YourClass.dismissKeyboard)`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from #selector, you can also see some of the new changes in Swift 2.2 from below link:

https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/

will not work in Swift 2.2 but okay in Swift 2.1

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self,
                        action: "addNewFireflyRefernce")
}

func addNewFireflyReference() {
    gratuitousReferences.append("We should start dealing in black-market beagles.")
}
```

will work in Swift 2.2 and higher version

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self,
                        action: #selector(addNewFireflyRefernce))
}

func addNewFireflyReference() {
    gratuitousReferences.append("Curse your sudden but inevitable betrayal!")
}
```

Also Swift 3.0 is coming soon:

https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-0-release-process/